# Query takes long time to execute while there is an index configured

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, optimization

We have a table with 190M records. there is an index on a fairly unique column but still, if I run a query on the table selecting top 10 with only the indexed column in the where and select clause it still takes ages to complete.

If I turn on live query plan sql server shows the 'waiting for query plan" waiting spinner. If the query finally finishes and if I run it again it then completes instantly. Even if I run DBCC FREEPROCCACHE before So it feels like the creation of the query plan is taking all the time but then i cannot reproduce by running DBCC FREEPROCCACHE before the query. After a while the same issue will reoccur.

[image]

Note: The database has 2 filegroups. Indexes and system databases are stored on SSD disk while normal table data is stored on a non SSD disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps auto-update stats kicked in. `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON` is your friend in that case. Check the index stats date to see if it coincides with the slowness:

```
SELECT 
    STATS_DATE(
          OBJECT_ID(N'YourSchema.YourTable')
        , INDEXPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(N'YourSchema.YourTable'),N'YourIndexName','IndexID')
    ) AS LastStatsDate;
```

-- [dan-guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman)

If it isn't plan generation (`SET STATISTICS TIME ON` can be revealing), or the query processing per se (reading just a few rows with a pretty unique index), then the natural thing to suspect is blocking. - [tibor-karaszi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi)

---

There are several ways to monitor for statistics update events (profiler, extended events...). SQL Server 2019 [introduces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sql-server-ver15#monitoring) the `WAIT_ON_SYNC_STATISTICS_REFRESH` wait type, which can appear in the wait information section of 'actual' execution plans.

[Sentry One Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) captures statistics building and refreshing (statman) and includes this information in the wait info.